# Gráfico de barras com frequência relativa e acumulada

Tags: r, gráfico, histograma

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de barras com a contagem em cima das barras e as frequências relativas e acumulada dos lados esquerdo e direito respectivamente mas não estou conseguindo.

Os dados são:

```
dput(x2)
    c(1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L)
```

As distribuições de frequência

```
table(x2)
x2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
4 8 8 5 8 3 2
```

Frequências relativas

```
prop.table(table(x2))
x2
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
0.10526316 0.21052632 0.21052632 0.13157895 0.21052632 0.07894737 0.05263158
```

O que estou tentando fazer é exatamente como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é resolvido com o pacote `ggplot2`. Em primeiro lugar, eu construo um data frame com tudo o que necessita ser plotado, com nomes que tenham algum significado neste contexto:

```
dados <- c(1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
           3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
           3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L)

dados.plot <- data.frame(table(dados), table(dados)/sum(table(dados)),
  cumsum(prop.table(table(dados))))
dados.plot <- dados.plot[, -3]
names(dados.plot) <- c("Categoria", "FreqAbsoluta", "FreqRelativa", 
  "FreqCumulativa")
dados.plot$FreqRelativa <- dados.plot$FreqRelativa*100
dados.plot
  Categoria FreqAbsoluta FreqRelativa FreqCumulativa
1         1            4    10.526316      0.1052632
2         2            8    21.052632      0.3157895
3         3            8    21.052632      0.5263158
4         4            5    13.157895      0.6578947
5         5            8    21.052632      0.8684211
6         6            3     7.894737      0.9473684
7         7            2     5.263158      1.0000000
```

Com o data frame `dados.plot` preparado, eu crio um gráfico de barras com a coluna `FreqRelativa`. A seguir, coloco os valores da `FreqAbsoluta` acima das barras do gráfico. Por fim, utilizo a função `sec_axis` para incluir um segundo eixo. Perceba que fiz uma transformação nos dados de `FreqCumulativa`, de modo que a linha acabasse na mesma altura do valor máximo das barras. Bastou tomar 100 (valor máximo de `FreqCumulativa`) e dividir pelo máximo de `FreqRelativa`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados.plot, aes(x=Categoria, y=FreqRelativa)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=FreqCumulativa*max(FreqRelativa), group=1)) +
  labs(x="Categoria", y="Frequência Relativa (%)") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=FreqAbsoluta), vjust=-0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis=sec_axis(trans=~ .*100/(max(dados.plot$FreqRelativa)), 
    name = "Frequência Cumulativa (%)"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As cores, legendas e outras características do gráfico podem ser ajustadas após uma consulta ao help do `ggplot2`.

Comment: É quase isso, mas não exatamente, a frequência relativa é o quociente da frequência absoluta de cada classe e a soma das frequências, que em geral é colocada em porcentagem. No lado esquerdo você colocou a frequência absoluta, que no caso eu gostaria de colocar em cima de cada barra.

Comment: De fato, eu não havia atentado para alguns detalhes. Veja o novo gráfico, por favor.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso.